# Howto prevent the form from submitting when i click on the save button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a form based on JSON feed, when the user click on "Save", I have bootstrap modal window showing up and form doesnt get submitted

But I noticed when I add this piece of code, the form is  getting submitted, I need this to populated the modal window and display a table in the modal window.

How can i prevent it from submitting?
Modified code:

```
 $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        var tablefeed= $('<tr><td>ID: '+key+'</td><td id="'+key+'">'+val+'</td><tr>').appendTo('#display');
    });
$(".modal-body").html(tablefeed);
```

I moved to ev.preventdefault as the @pmandell had suggested and that worked

```
      <script type="text/javascript">





   $('#myform').on('submit', function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serializeObject();
    json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
     $("#results").text(json_data); 
     $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
         $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            var tablefeed= $('<tr><td>ID: '+key+'</td><td id="'+key+'">'+val+'</td><tr>').appendTo('#display');
        });
    $(".modal-body").html(tablefeed); 





    }); 



        });
```

Comment: Just return false in the .submit() event

Comment: Either do the above, or call the preventDefault() method on the event object: event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
...
```